# C++ Class Internal Memory Management

Tags: c++, memory-management, copy, heap-memory, local

I am building some generic classes Object and Array that can be used to store data and output data into various formats (JSON, XML, etc.). I want to be able to do something like this:

```
Object * o1 = new Object();
Object * o2 = new Object();
Object * o3 = new Object();
o3.addNVP("obj1",o1);
o3.addNVP("obj2",o2);
o3.printJSON();
```

Output:

```
{"obj1":{},"obj2":{}}
```

However, since the deconstructor in Object always calls delete on any internal Object pointers, I'm afraid users of this class might attempt to do something like this:

```
Object o1;
Object * o2 = new Object();
o2->addNVP("obj1", &o1);
...
delete o2; //runtime error because o2 internally will attempt to delete &o1!
```

What is the best way to mitigate this potential runtime error? Good documentation? Deep Copying instead of taking incoming references as-is? Remove that feature altogether and make everyone allocate new objects with `Object * o2 = o1.createSubObject("obj2")`? I'm just not sure what I need to worry about in terms of memory management.

Comment: deep copying (if appropriate) or std::shared_ptr. Other possibilities are dangerous, even o1.createSubObject("obj2") as you can store pointer somewhere and use it after destruction.

Comment: Why do you want Object to delete pointers passed to it as arguments?